# Sublimelinter - jshint - see field causing warning

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

I am using Sublime Text 3 with SublimeLinter (v3.7.4) and SublimeLinter-jshint (v1.2.1). I am getting a warning from the linter in my code and it prints at the bottom of the window something like:

`2 of 3 errors: Expected and assignment or function call and isntead saw an expression, Line 17, Column 36`. Now I know that this warning is coming from my `.jshintrc` file where I define `"expr" : true`. However, I do not always know where these warnings are coming from. So is there a setting in the `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` file where I can tell the linter to print the cause of the warning?

And so then, at the bottom of the Sublime Text window it would read something like:
`2 of 3 errors: Expected and assignment or function call and isntead saw an expression, caused by 'expr: true', Line 17, Column 36`

Answer (score 1):

All Sublime Linter does is process the input it receives from Jshint; if Jshint doesn't give out that information, then Sublime Linter can't process and display it. Have you tried linting the file with Jshint through the command line? Then you can see what input Sublime Linter receives to show you. If 'expr' isn't there, then it's probably impossible.

I have switched to Eslint; that linter always tells you which rule an error/warning is coming from. It also gave me better information than Jshint, so maybe it's just a better (more comprehensive) linter than Eslint; but I haven't tested Jshint beyond the fact that it couldn't point out the error I wanted it to point out, so perhaps it has other advantages. You can test both Jshint and Eslint online in a web app to compare them.

Comment: Yeah I ended up switching to ESLint. You can also view the console of Sublime (in Mac OS X ^`) and that always shows a verbose print out, might work in jshint also? I switched to ESLint before I could check

Comment: @Jeremy: Hmm that would be worth a try; to be honest, I've only tried Jshint online, where it didn't point to the column (only to the line) of my error in a very long multi-part string, and it gave the wrong reason ("missing semicolon", while in reality I had forgotten a plus sign in the construction of the long string). So I don't expect it to tell us more, but it is possible...